# Let $X = \{a,b,c\}$. Find a measure space $(X × X × X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ so that $\int_{X × X × X} \,d\mu =1$.

Tags: measure-theory, product-space

Let $X = \{a,b,c\}$. Find a measure space $(X × X × X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ so that $\int_{X × X × X} \,d\mu =1$.

This question has me somewhat stumped because I'm not sure how to approach integrating over a space made up of finite points instead of something like an interval or $\mathbb{R}$. I'm assuming something similar to the counting measure could work. Maybe a measure that is equal to 1 for all sets except the empty set? Would that still be equal to 1 when integrating over the space X × X × X?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: There are $27$ points. Assign mass $\frac 1 {27}$ to each point.

Comment: Or assign 1 to one point and 0 to the others

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by assign. Do you mean somehow modify the measure so it is equal to a certain value if the set contains a certain point?

Comment: By “assign” he simply means “define it to be”.

Comment: So like a condition. For example $\mu$(A) = 1 if $a \in A$ , $\mu$(A) = 0 else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ is a measure space then *automatically* we have $\Omega\in\mathcal A$ and $\int_{\Omega}d\mu=\mu(\Omega)$.

So in order to get $\int_{\Omega}d\mu=1$ it is enough that $\mu(\Omega)=1$.

To keep things as simple as possible we can choose for $\mathcal A=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$. Then $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and the function $\mu:\mathcal A\to[0,\infty]$ prescribed by $\varnothing\mapsto0$ and $\Omega\mapsto1$ is a measure on measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$. Then the triple $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ can be recognized as a *measure space* with $\int_{\Omega}d\mu=1$.

The looks of set $\Omega\neq\varnothing$ are not really important. We can indeed go for $\Omega=X\times X\times X$ where $X=\{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: any probability space is satisfies the answer? or this is exactly what the question is asking: prove there exists a probability space ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, every probability space satisfies. It is the construction of a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ that satisfies the answer without any condition on $\Omega$. Then the OP can substitute $X\times X\times X$ for $\Omega$ and is ready.

Comment: Smart approach! I went for the option with defining the measure to be equal to one if and only if the point a is in the set, but I see how the probability space works too.